# Snap SVG, can't access element inside DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, snap.svg

I have a little problem, which I try to solve.
I have a set up like that: Its not the whole code, but I wanted to show you the where and when i call my functions.
**Index.html**

```
...doctype, header etc.
<body>
<svg id="viewer" width="1200" height="1200"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/viewer.js"></script>
</body>
```

**viewer.js**

```
var s=Snap("#viewer");
function createSec(i) {
var sec = s.group();
var file= "../images/background.svg";
var bg = Snap.load(file, function (loadedFragment) {
    sec.clear();
    sec.append(loadedFragment);

    var block = s.rect(x, curY, width, height);

    block.attr({
        id: "rec"+i+"-"+j,
        fill: "red",
        stroke: "#1f2c39",
        strokeWidth: 1
    });
    var text = s.text((x + 2.5), (curY + 10), "Text"+i+"."+j);
    text.attr({
        id: "tex"+i+"-"+j,
        'font-size':10
    });
    sec.append(block);
    sec.append(text);
    curY += stepY;

});
}  
function getSection(id) {
    console.log("Cursec: "+document.getElementById("rec1-1"));
    console.log("Cursec2: "+s.select("#rec1-1"));
}  
function init() {
    for(i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
        createSec(i);
    }
    window.setTimeout(getSection(2),5000);
}  
init();
```

Now my problem.
The code works well, I load a background and add some rectangles with some text inside ontop of the background. I can inspect the DOM (with firefox&chrome) and it looks like i want it to be. If I type `document.getElementById("rec1-1")` in the firefox console i get what i want e.g: `<rect x="532.32309375" y="197.358875" width="132.3538125" height="117.69547500000002" id="rec1-1">`
but my `getSection()` function always echos `Cursec:null & Cursec2:null` to the console.
What am I doing wrong? I can access the DOM from the browser console, but not within Snap SVG.

Comment: j is undefined, no?

Comment: no j is defined, I just cutted some parts of the code, because it would be to long all variables a defined. I see in the DOM that it creates everything correct. But why is getSection() not able to access the DOM correctly, even if I hardcode the css selector into it, which is working in firefox & chrome.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. With Emphasis on the **C** and **V**

Comment: Here is the whole code like I use it: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vw6382u6/2/) ..background 1&2 are Triangles just for your information

Comment: ../images/background1.svg doesn't exist in the fiddle so the onload code is not run and no rects are created.

Comment: Works fine for me with valid svg files, and Cursec and Cursec2 show rect elements.

Comment: Strange used w3c validator for my files and they get validated. If i print out the selected elements I get only empty <g></g> but in firefox, these are filled with attributes like they should...@Ian do you load a SVG from a file or do you load it from a HTML file?

Comment: Sorry, missed this. I just load it from a .svg file.